# Get height of non-rendered text in a Win8 app?

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-8

I have a data class with a member function that creates UI elements at run-time based on the current instance.  I would like to be able to size the output UI elements based on the currently in-use text size.  How can I find the height (in pixels) of rendered text?

Specifically, I would like to create a grid of uniform squares based on a multiple (~1.5) of the height of a rendered "0".

I have tried creating a TextBlock and getting ActualHeight, however, this always returns 0... presumably because the TextBlock is never actually displayed.  Even using UpdateLayout on the instance of the TextBlock didn't update the ActualHeight value.

Is there another way?

NB Auto-sizing doesn't work for me, because I have some empty elements which shrink to 0 when I do that.  I need to size all elements appropriately, whether or not they have text, based on the size of the current font in use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Windows 8 / WinRT API set, but `System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureText` should still work.

Comment: No, the System.Drawing namespace is not available in Windows Store apps.